# flask_sqlalchemy use hash of string as primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I modify this example to use a `sha256` value for the `username` field as `primary key`, instead of the `autoincremented index`?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Example taken from here: 
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: You should never use a hash as a primary key. Hashes are not unique. What is wrong with autoincremented index? That is the best choice for practically every primary key.

Comment: I don't want to insert duplicate usernames.

Comment: If you don't want to insert duplicate usernames, then you have to make the username unique. And you did that already. It is fine the way it is.

Comment: I want to use a similar table, but with URLs, instead of usernames. URLs can be quite long and I was thinking about `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I've added the `unique` constraint on the `hash_url` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this but the simplest one to get what you want is in your routes.py file:

```
...
from hashlib import sha256

@app.route('/register') 
def register():

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username_hash = sha256(form.username.data.encode()).hexdigest()
        user = User(id=username_hash)
     ...
```

As you can see there's a couple parts to this. The username is usually going to be a `str` which has to be called `encode` on to become of type `bytes`. Then just calling the sha256 from the standard library and `hexdigest` is the method that returns the value for the hash.

Having a 'unique' hash can be useful but so can having a unique integer id which will not be repeated and can be easily referenced down the line. For debugging and looking up Users in the `flask-shell` it might be easier to do a lookup by a simple integer rather than other attributes or a hash.

This might be simpler to do:

```
User.query.get(14)
```

Than using a hash for primary id.

Comment: I've added the `unique` constraint on the `hash_url` column. Thank you for explaining the logic.